# getting error: Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

When i run my react app i am getting error `Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 11.x` , can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? i am using `node -v 11.15` and using `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: use `yarn add node-sass` in this case.. and it'll install
and if you don't have yarn.. `npm i -g yarn`

Comment: I tried but still getting same error